# Distance of Pivot from the Rear axle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, structures, strength

I am designing an NSAM crane. I have encountered the following issue when designing the vehicle:

Generally the pivot(or the point about which the NSAM crane rotates) is in the center. But from two online sources(https://patents.google.com/patent/US8002074, https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.7158/M12-108.2014.12.1) I have found that if the pivot is in the center, then the NSAM crane has easy maneuverability and tip over stability. If the pivot is away from the center and towards the rear axle, the roll over stability is more.

Even though some calculations have been given in the sources, I am not able to understand why this is the case and which stability is more important for the NSAM crane?

Also please help me with any Simply supported beam type of calculations for the stability if any.

Any references would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Centre of gravity cf. centre of rotation and / or roll?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [rather exhaustive dissertation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269755529_A_general_articulation_angle_stability_model_for_non-slewing_articulated_mobile_cranes_on_slopes) regarding this particular type of crane, Non Slewing Articulated Mobile, based on a study of apparent out-of-balance situations in Australia.

Formulae are provided as well as diagrams of center of gravity calculations on flat and sloped surfaces.

[image: nasm crane identification]

[image: more nasm info]

The above link also includes a download of the entire document in PDF. There is a substantial section containing the formulae and more diagrams that may be of use to your research.